# Show tick symbol on label

Tags: c#, unicode

How can I show "√" (tick symbol) in label text?

Comment: That's no "tick symbol", that's *U+221A Square Root*. Were you looking for *U+2713 Check Mark* (✓) or *U+2714 Heavy Check Mark* (✔)? You'll get font issues with the latter ones, probably, though. But mis-using a square root as a check mark sounds like Ye Olde DOS days.

Comment: @Joey It seems Windows XP does not have those characters in the "Arial Unicode MS" Font [see this discussion](http://www.debugging.com/bug/19689). A possible workaround would be to use Wingdings to display the check mark and a different font to display the text.

Comment: (a) Arial Unicode MS is not a Windows font, it comes with Office. (b) It's a fallback font, not intended for actual use anywhere. This is mostly because it stopped at Unicode 2, has no features at all except for the load of glyphs (i.e. you'll get wrong diacritics in nearly every case), etc. Don't use it and you'll be happier.

Comment: It is not a tick symbol, but it works in itextsharp in Arial font, U+2713 Check Mark (✓) or U+2714 Heavy Check Mark (✔) does not work for me in Arial.

Comment: That symbol you are showing in your question looks like a [part of square root symbol ;)](http://www.scientificpsychic.com/etc/square-root.html) +1 for asking the question in advance.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

This code will do it for you:

```
LblTick.Text  = ((char)0x221A).ToString();
```

Edit:

or even easier:

```
lblTick.Text = "\u221A";
```

Edit 2:

And, as pointed out in a comment, that code (221A) is actually a square root symbol, not a tick.
To use the true tick mark, you can use the following:

```
lblTick.Text = "\u2713";
```

or for a heavy tick mark, you can use the following (but you may get font issues with this one):

```
lblTick.Text = "\u2714";
```

(Credit to @Joey for that comment!)

Comment: You don't need ToString here, just create the string directly: `"\u221A"`.

Comment: is there any way to make this symbol, bold & colorful ?

Comment: @user1010399 Yes, change the font/color.

Answer (score 9):

You can also use

```
lblTick.Text="\u2714";
```

Answer (score 3):

The [Extended ASCII code](http://www.asciitable.com/) for that symbol is 251.

You could probably also do,

```
char c = '√';
Console.WriteLine("{0}", c);
```

Comment: Don't _ever_ use "Extended ASCII" unless it's a DOS-based program. (There are a few dozen charsets that use the same 128-256 range - DOS cpXXX, windows-125X, iso-8859-X...)

Comment: ...okay, DOS-based or Windows Console-based.

Comment: Written that way, Visual Studio will save the file as Unicode anyway, though, which doesn't hurt, then.

Answer (score 3):

This should work as well:

```
<asp:Label ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="&#8730;"></asp:Label>
```

Comment: this is the only solution that worked for me. what i did what copy over your text and in codebehinde say Button1.text = "&#8730"